# Do objects that are within other objects really share the same address?

Tags: c++, object, memory

I recently ran into this question while I was working on a project, and it confused me a bit.  So I decided to write a test program to get a definitive answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class layer3{
public:
    layer3(){}
    ~layer3(){}     
private:

};


class layer2{
public:
    layer2(){}
    ~layer2(){}

    layer3* GetBAddress(){return &b;}
private:
    layer3 b;
};


class layer1{
public:
    layer1(){}
    ~layer1(){}

    //returns the address of a, which is a 'layer2' object
    layer2* GetaAddress(){return &a;}
    //returns the address of b, which is is a layer 3 object
    layer3* GetDeepBAddress(){return a.GetBAddress();}
private:
    layer2 a;

};

int main(){

    layer1 t;
    cout << &t << "  : layer 1's address" << endl;
    cout << t.GetaAddress() <<  "  : layer 2's address" <<endl;
    cout << t.GetDeepTLAddress() <<  "  : layer 3's address" <<endl;

}
```

This program creates 3 objects. layer2 is created inside layer1, and layer3 is created inside layer2.  Then I call to get the addresses of layer1, layer2, and layer3, and just as was happening before, this is the output:

```
$ ./a.exe
0x28ac4f  : layer 1's address
0x28ac4f  : layer 2's address
0x28ac4f  : layer 3's address
```

How can all three of these objects share the same spot in memory?  What if I scaled this program to have 50 layers (objects)?  Or 10,000?  I'm not quite sure how this is possible.  Can someone please put me in my place and explain what's going on here?

**Edit:** Perhaps it's because I instantiated the objects in private rather than in the objects' constructors?  Baah I don't know.

Comment: It's not weird, and it's certainly not an optimization. It's really the most naive object layout algorithm that one could think of.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, You're right, I was thinking there was some additional space between the member and the beginning of the object for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most definitive answer is that given by the C++ standard:

> Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

That is, if an object is a subject of another, they may have the same address.

In C++11, a *standard-layout struct* (despite its name, that can be a `class` too) object's first member is guaranteed to have the same address as the object itself:

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

Since your classes are all standard-layout, the behaviour you've observed is guaranteed by C++11.

In C++03, the rule is similar, but applies to *POD-struct* types, rather than *standard-layout struct* types. Your classes, however, are not *POD-struct* types because they have user-defined destructors. So the behaviour you see here is *not guaranteed* by C++03.

So why can this occur? Well all a class really is is a way to group some data together and provide operations on that data. Consider a class that just contains an `int` like so:

```
class A
{
  int x;
};
```

All this class is made up of is that `int`. When you create an object of type `A`, all you're really doing is allocating enough space for its innards and initialising them (or in this case, not initialising them). Let's say we create two instances of `A`:

```
A a1;
A a2;
```

What do we have in memory? You could imagine that it looks like this:

```
   a1     a2
┌──────┬──────┐┄┄
│  A   │  A   │
└──────┴──────┘┄┄
Memory ------->
```

If we know that `A` just contains an `int` - that is, an `A` object is really *nothing more* than an `int` (except for maybe some padding) - then we know that the memory actually looks something like this if we break it down a bit more:

```
   a1     a2
┌──────┬──────┐┄┄
│ int  │ int  │
└──────┴──────┘┄┄
Memory ------->
```

You can see here that the `A` and `int` would both have the same address because the `int` is a subobject of the objects of type `A`. If `A` contained both an `int` and a `char`, it might look something like this:

```
       a1            a2
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐┄┄
│ int  │ char │ int  │ char │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘┄┄
Memory ------->
```

We know that `char` will have a higher address than the `int` because, once again, the standard says so:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object.

Note that a subobject does not *necessarily* share its address with the object its contained within, even if it's the first one. It's entirely up to the compiler.

Comment: It might be worth noting that since 2011, standard-layout classes always have the same address as their first data member; so the observations in the question are guaranteed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks! Added that and the equivalent point from C++03 (although it doesn't apply to the example given by the asker).

Comment: So memory addresses are only given to blocks of memory _after_ the space is allocated for the given object / structure / whatever?  For whatever dumb reason (probably because I'm dumb) I was under the impression that memory had it's memory addresses engrained by the operating system on startup, sorta like houses on a street (where the addresses never change but whatever is in the house can change);

Comment: @xcdemon05 The memory is allocated for an object and that memory location has a certain address. What makes you think the addresses are assigned afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

In memory, an instance of a class (generally) occupies the space of its data members (plus a virtual table pointer or other implementation defined bits).

From a purely data member point of view, an instance of `layer1` contains only an instance of `layer2`, so it's natural that the first element stored in `layer1` (the one which has the same address as the `layer1` instance itself) is the `layer2` instance. The same reasoning applies to `layer2` and `layer3`.

Comment: So while the objects do not all physically sit together in the same spot in memory, they do all get pointed to from the same spot in memory?

Comment: They do all sit together in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find anything weird in what you are observing. An object is comprised of its members written one after the other in the memory and thus an objects' address and the address of its first member are the same. Will be like that no matter how many layers you have.

Answer (score 0):

It's just how objects are stored in memory. C++ only makes some guarantees on how member objects are ordered - a lot of stuff is up to the compiler - alignment, switching members around (subject to the restrictions). Why add memory or offset members when you don't have to? If the addresses were not the same, you'd have objects with unused memory.

As a test, you can add a `virtual` function to `layer2` and see what happens.